# Datatables change options individually

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm working with datatables and i ran into this problem.

I have multi tables in one page (as well as in my system), all of them have commom options, like the datasource, responsive, etc..
But some of the tables have some unique options, like bSort, aoColumns and so on...

So my question is: Can i initialize all of them with the commom options and then change those options separate?

---

Right now, this is how i'm doing:

```
var TabClienteFisico_01 = $('#cfisico').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: false,
    aoColumns : [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nm_cliente" },
        { "mData": "cpf" },
        { "mData": "tel" },
        { "mData": "cidade" }
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data/c_fisico.json",
    },
    "dataType": "json"
});

var TabClienteFisico_02 = $('#cfisico2').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: false,
    bSort: false,
    aoColumns: [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nm_cliente" },
        { "mData": "cpf" }
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data/c_fisico.json",
    },
    "dataType": "json"
});
```

And this is what i'd like to do:

```
var mainTab = $('.mainTab').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data/c_fisico.json",
    },
    "dataType": "json"
});
var TabClienteFisico_01 = $('#cfisico1').dataTable({
    aoColumns: [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nm_cliente" },
        { "mData": "cpf" },
        { "mData": "tel" },
        { "mData": "cidade" }
    ]
});
var TabClienteFisico_02 = $('#cfisico2').dataTable({
    bSort: false,
    aoColumns: [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nm_cliente" },
        { "mData": "cpf" }
    ]
});
```

And in the HTML it would be:

```
<table id="cfisico1" class"mainTab"> ... </table>
<table id="cfisico2" class"mainTab"> ... </table>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend option object passed as parameter to datatable method, e.g:

```
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: false
};

var opt01 = $.extend({}, options, {
    aoColumns: [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nm_cliente" },
        { "mData": "cpf" },
        { "mData": "tel" },
        { "mData": "cidade" }
    ]
});
var opt02 = $.extend({}, options, {
    bSort: false,
    aoColumns: [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nm_cliente" },
        { "mData": "cpf" }
    ]
});

var TabClienteFisico_01 = $('#cfisico1').dataTable(opt01),
    TabClienteFisico_02 = $('#cfisico2').dataTable(opt02);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is going to make it easier to create/edit my tables =D